# How to dismiss modal view controller using UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uialertview

I'd like to dismiss the whole modal view controller by tapping cancel on the UIAlertView that I implemented. The alert view asks the user if he wants to logout and if the user taps Yes, it'll dismiss the modal view controller.

How can I do this in Xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by checking out the documentation on uialertviewdelegate.

First you need to declare your class as the delegate for the uialertview and then implement the method to get the index of button that the user has clicked.

You can use these methods to check the user's choice

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: I know those methods. I just can't make it to work to dismiss the modal view controller.

Comment: In one of those methods you will need to call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: I was able to make it work using this code: `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"OK");
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use alert view delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

In case you have  more than OK button, you need to mention button index, i.e.

```
  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

  if(buttonIndex==0)
   {
     //Do something 
   }

  if(buttonIndex==1)
   {
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an alertView to dismiss a modal view controller,

Use didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex instead of clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

The latter causes a crash.